# Multimeter shows voltage on metal cage of my new Standing Fan!

Tags: voltage, motor, multimeter, isolation, fan

A few days ago I bought an electrical fan, with 5x aluminum blades. After I installed and put it to work, I noticed, using a simple indicator screwdriver, that the metal cage/fence was in contact with the voltage! :(

I decided to take a measurement with a digital multimeter (EMOS-MD220), and the result was 55V.

Metal cage with engine chassis, joined with 4 metal screws.

The front of the engine box is black metal. The chassis shows no contact with the voltage, but the screw sockets indicate that it is in contact! Apparently the chassis is painted with some insulating material, and only the holes where the screws are fixed, are without insulation.

Please can you give me some help on this situation? Is it normal for an standing fan to show such voltage?

Comment: Voltage is a difference. Where is the other probe of the multimeter touching?

Comment: I do not agree that the question is off-topic. On the contrary, it is closely related to the topic of the Electrical Engineering section. See how meaningful the answer below is. This addiction to closing interesting questions is detrimental to the platform and should not be tolerated.

Comment: This could also just be a duplicate. Every now and then someone asks why a device appears to have AC on metal chassis. Also this case has very little info what kind of connection the device has and how it is wired up. Device make and model would be nice, or even better a link to installation manual how it should be installed.

Comment: @Justme, I agree with this particular point of view.  But I have noticed that it is difficult for beginners to realize and make a connection between these simple but important facts - that there is alternating current, capacitive connection and high resistance of the voltmeter. For them, it is something supernatural how there is voltage on the "floating" chassis of the device... Another similar question that torments them is how a voltage tester lights up when there is no connection to the neutral wire...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you measured voltage between the chassis and Earth from a nearby socket. If you put one probe on the fan and the other somewhere else that isn't Earth, then you're not measuring voltage to Earth, which is what matters for safety.

There's always a bit of capacitance between the wires and the metal chassis, and that lets a tiny bit of current through. Combined with the multimeter's very high resistance, this means the multimeter will measure a voltage.

The same thing happens when you take the lightbulb out and stick the multimeter probes into the bulb socket to check if the problem is the bulb or a lack of power. Even if the switch is off, the multimeter will usually measure some voltage due to capacitance between wires in the same conduit.

Multimeters marketed to electricians usually include a "Low Z" setting that uses a much lower input resistance, which fixes these issues.

Now, when you installed the fan, I'm sure you checked if it was [Class 2 double-insulated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appliance_classes#Class_II) (does not require protection earth) or [Class 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appliance_classes#Class_I) which requires Earth.

If it is Class 1, then obviously there should not be any voltage between Earth from a socket and the fan chassis, because you connected the Earth wire to the corresponding terminal in the fan. If there is voltage, then you connected it wrong, or there's a problem with the Earth wire, or some other cause that needs to be fixed. Class 1 appliances are not designed to be safe without Earth.

If it is Class 2, your measurement is pretty much normal.

Comment: In such cases, a good old test lamp is better than an electronic voltmeter...

Comment: Yes, 20W incandescent lamp is my favorite

Comment: And my favorite in laboratory and cars  is 12 (5 - 24) V voltage tester lamp...